# How to handle HBS function call in Node JS

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to make a sign-in log-in form. Here I want to pass an event on button click of the sign-in and add a class to it. But I can't able to find any solution to this .

```
<div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
            <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
            <p>To keep connected with us please login with your personal info</p>
            <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't something you will handle with Node JS. Anything having to do with user interaction and the DOM happens in the user's browser, longer after Node has sent processed and responded to the HTTP request. The solution to your problem starts with a click handler in client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Sir, how can I make a dynamic website with Html and connect it to some JS library without using simple JS we use to learn first with HTML , CSS

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question. You will need to use some JavaScript - simple or otherwise - to add a click event listener to your button. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: I am asking if we can push a Node JS website on google but can we push this website on google, which is also made by JS (which we study first for the basics)